# How to subset a vector of sentences containing a given word

Tags: regex, string, r, subset

Let's say I have a vector of sentences:

```
Vector
Juan is searching for a magazine.
Julia searched her car.
Go to the market to buy eggs.
Your name is unsearchable.
Search for me when you get to Paris.
Can you search for a low cost solution?
```

I want a subset of this vector that only contains the entries with the word "search" or its variations (i.e. searched, unsearchable, Search).  In excel, I might use something like `ISNUMBER(SEARCH("search",A1))` to find out which cells in  column `A1` containing the word "`search`".

It seems to me that `grep` may be the function I'm looking for, but I can't figure out how to use it appropriately.

Comment: You need the `value=TRUE` argument to grep.  `grep('search', Vector, value=TRUE)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `vector` is your specified vertor:

```
> grep("search", vector, ignore.case=TRUE)
[1] 1 2 4 5 6
> vector[grep("search", vector, ignore.case=TRUE)]
[1] "Juan is searching for a magazine."      
[2] "Julia searched her car."                
[3] "Your name is unsearchable."             
[4] "Search for me when you get to Paris."   
[5] "Can you search for a low cost solution?"
```